# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_numeric' in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The following code is throwing AttributeError on a server where the version of Pandas is 0.16.2 whereas it runs fine on my machine where version is 0.20.

```
df = pandas.read_csv('filename', header = None, error_bad_lines = False, warn_bad_lines =True,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

df = df.drop(df[pandas.to_numeric(df[599], errors='coerce').isnull()].index)
```

The error message is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_model.py", line 11, in <module>
    df = df.drop(df[pandas.to_numeric(df[599], errors='coerce').isnull()].index)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'
```

Is there a way to avoid this error in 0.16.2 version? The update to the server is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you notice in the pandas documentation of what's new in version 0.17,
you shall notice

> pd.to_numeric is a new function to coerce strings to numbers (possibly with coercion) (GH11133)

Hence, pandas 0.16 does not have the function `pd.to_numeric` . However you can use this function to achieve the same purpose.

```
df = df.drop(df[df[599].astype(float).isnull()].index)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas.to_numeric is only available for version 0.17 and higher. You can use [DataFrame.convert_objects](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) with `convert_numeric=True` argument instead, errors are automatically coerced.

```
df = df.drop(df[df[599].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).isnull()].index)
```

Comment: There is a syntax problem here. Can you please cross-check?

Comment: @user3667569 oops sorry about that, I failed to correctly copy and past `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` into your code. Didn't realize you were dropping null fields. For that you can use `.dropna()` and it should do the same thing if I correctly understood your logic.

Comment: I am not dropping NULL fields. The intention of my code was to remove any rows from the dataframe which have a non-float value in column 599.

Comment: Right then, you can directly exchange the `pandas.to_numeric(df[599], errors='coerce')` with `df[599].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` and it will work. In version 0.17 it has been deprecated for more explicit to_numeric function. Which does the same thing, I'll remove the dropna() part for clearness sake.